# How to use 2 python mods when they both require different python versions

Tags: python, pygame, version, pymssql

How would I use 2 different python mods in the same file when both mods require different python versions?  I am trying to write a program that uses pygame, which only works with 3.2 and pymssql, which only works with 3.3.  I get errors if I try to run them both in the same file(on either python version), but not if I run them separately.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115440/python-3-3-pygame-installation
That should solve your problem.

Comment: Cool thanks.  I didn't know about bitbucket.  I was going straight to pygame.org.  Is it safe to run code from a community site like bitbucket?

Comment: Well, I plan to use it. I haven't used it yet though.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple solution for you. In my opinion, it is the pygame communitie's responsibility to make it work on Python 3.3. Python 3.3 has a higher potential to be widely distributed than Python 3.2. Also, "supporting Python 3" nowadays should mean supporting Python 3.3/3.4, and not only Python 3.2. I guess this is on the todo list of the pygame maintainers. If in doubt, you might want to ask on the corresponding forums/mailing list if supporting Python 3.3 is already planned.

If you are curious and not frightened, you might event want to dig into *why* pygame fails on Python 3.3 and start fixing issue by issue. I guess this effort will be highly appreciated.

Edit:

I was assuming that you did your research homework a bit :-) Looks like pygame *is* available for Python 3.3:
https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/downloads
Thanks @batbrat.