# how to print in python a simple string

Tags: python, python-3.x, centos, centos6.5

I have centos 6.5
If I type python, I get:

```
Python 3.3.2 (default, Oct 30 2013, 08:01:17) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux
```

I created a file 1.py  with:

```
print "Goodbye, World!"
```

I do `python ./1.py`
I get

```
  File "./1.py", line 1
    print "Goodbye, World!"
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print("Goodbye, World!")
```

[`print`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function) is a function in Python 3

Comment: obviously, not, tis fixed the issue :-)

Comment: @Ben. [No](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html): Python 3.0, also known as “Python 3000” or “Py3K”, is the *first ever intentionally backwards incompatible* Python release.

Comment: @Andy Should I go with 3* branch? I am just learning for fun +pygame

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka, the general recommendation is that new development should go with Python 3, unless you have to use a library that is in red on this [page](https://python3wos.appspot.com/). Those have not been migrated to Python 3 yet

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka You might run across [problems like this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14115440/1860929) if using 3.3, so keep those nitty gritty details in mind. If I were doing it for fun, I would go with python 2.7, because, why would I want to spoil my fun with such stupid issues.

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka, [Pygame 1.9.2 supports Python 3.2 and up. Only the orphaned _movie module (not built by default) does not.](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Does%20Pygame%20work%20with%20Python%203?)

Comment: Much appreciated all for the help

Answer (score 0):

[print](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function) is a function in python 3, the syntax you've used corresponds to python2.

So, you need to do

```
print("Goodbye, World!")
```