# How to download pygame for python 3.x (More specific 3.3)

Tags: python, module, pygame

So this is probably a dumb question to ask but I would like to download and install the python module pygame. I've got a 64-bit operating system and python version 3.3. Anyone who has an easy guide on how to download and install it easy. I'm on windows by the way!

Comment: Do yourself a favour and upgrade your python version, your os is also relevant to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Pygame installation for Python 3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115440/pygame-installation-for-python-3-3):

> The main Pygame page seems to be rarely updated. You can download
>   Pygame releases direct from Bitbucket at
>   https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/downloads.

Edit: For some reason I thought you specifically said "Windows".  My answer only applies to the Windows OS.  Can you please specify your OS?